# Why doesn't the linear regression preserve the standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, regression

If we model $Y = \beta X$, we can estimate $\beta$ to minimize

$$\sum (Y_i - \beta X_i)^2$$

Taking derivatives and solving for 0, we get $\sum 2\beta X_i^2 - 2Y_1X_i = 0 \implies \beta = \frac{\sum Y_i X_i}{\sum X_i^2}.$

Why does our best fit for $Y = \beta X$ not even satisfy that it has the same variance?

Comment: Hi: Have the same variance as what ?

Comment: As $Y$. The variance of $Y$ can be calculated. It will not equal the variance of $\beta X$, unless $\beta = \sigma_Y  / \sigma_X$.

Comment: @ammo45 -- what is your reasoning $Var(Y)$ should be the same as $Var(\beta X)$?

Comment: Why shouldn't our model for $Y$ be able to replicate the same variance as $Y$? Surely that is a major flaw in our model?

Comment: @ammo45 -- Even with your "explanation" I still can't see a flaw in the model when variances differ. Simple example: the waiter of a beach café has no fixed basic salary, he is payed by 10% of _his_ sales (plus tips). He prepares a diagram to demonstrate his situation to the tax authority. At rainy days there are no guests, hence no sales no tips. Thus a "line through $(0, 0)$"-model fits well. Now take a look to the variance, $Var(X)$ has a pretty different unit than $Var(Y)$ -- ${guests}^2$ vs ${bugs}^2$ -- what is your reasoning they should be the same? Explain please.

Comment: I'm not saying they should be the same, I'm saying it would be nice if they were. Why aren't they?

Comment: It would be nice if the model were perfect, that is, if $Y=\beta X$, but in most real-world cases the data do not cooperate in that way, and we are stuck with $Y\neq\beta X$ no matter how we choose $\beta$. We must choose which properties of the actual $Y$ are most important for us to capture in the model. I think of linear regression as being useful as a predictor, that is, the next time I see an $X$ value I can make a good guess what the $Y$ value will be. Since I know the value of $X$ in that case, the variance of $\beta X$ seems irrelevant. How would you use it?

Comment: Hi: I don't see why you would expect Var(y) to be equal to Var($\beta X$) ?  Var($y$) is the variance of y without respect to a fitted model. The goal of a model is to explain the variance of $y$ so it's not clear to me why would expect var($\beta X$) to be equal to Var($y$) ?

Comment: @markleeds Let's say you have 10 billion values of $x$ and $y$. However, because you're clumsy, you accidentally delete the last 5 billion values of $y$. In order to cover up your mistake, you replace the deleted 5 billion values of $y$ with $\beta x$. 

However, anybody looking at a time-series of $y$ will be able to spot the error, since there will be a clear change in volatility of the series after the halfway point. 

And thus your plan is foiled.

Comment: Note: `><((((*>`

Comment: Hi ammo 45: thanks for your response and the interesting example. I'm curious what happens to the volatility after the halfway point ? I think you're stating that the volatility of the faked $y_t$ is less than the volatility of the non-faked $y_t$ because the series is linear and deterministic ? So, the volatility of the series after the halfway point will be less ? Not clear where you're taking this concept but I think that's what you are saying. Thanks for confirmation or de-confirmation.

Comment: Also, when you write $y = \beta X$, there are no time subscripts . So, are you restricting to the case where one has a classical linear regression model or are you including time-series regression ( in your comments and in your example to me, your framework was more time series based so I think you meant to include time subscripts ) ? Classical OLS and time series regression are similar but not really the same thing. I ask because that difference might matter regarding the answer you provide above.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the measured data -- for example it forms a "dot cloud" with a distinct distance to the origin -- it might be reasonable to set as balance line the line from the origin through the dot cloud's barycentre $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ instead of a "best fit" according the [LS method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) using vertical distances of the observed points to the resulting line as target figure.

The slope of this line through the origin is $\displaystyle\beta=\frac {\sum_k y_k}{\sum_k x_k}=\frac{\bar{y}}{\bar{x}}$.

(This conforms to what I remember from studies decades ago.)

Comment: The line through $(0,0)$ and $(\bar x, \bar y)$ does not usually minimise the sum of squares of the residuals over all lines through $(0,0)$

Comment: @Henry -- Yes, I know. But please take a look to the diagram in your answer. Even it's constructed its apt to show what _could_ be more reasonable, a line from the origin through $(\bar x, \bar y)$ or one with minimised sum of squares of the residuals.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.  One is that with simple regression (allowing an intercept) you would expect the variance of the fitted values to be less than that of the observations unless there is a perfect fit: indeed this is what originally caused it to be called regression. The other is that forcing the regression line through the origin can lead to peculiar results if that is not the actual relationship.

As an illustration, consider linear regression with the observations $(1,25)$, $(2,21)$, $(3,23)$, $(4,24)$, $(5,22)$.

- If you allow an intercept, then the fitted line is $\hat y_i = 23.9 -0.3x_i$ and so the variance of the $\hat y_i$ is $R^2=0.09$ times the variance of the $y_i$, largely because the linear relationship appears to to be weak. (See the points and regression line in black below). To get the variance of the $\hat y_i$  up to that of the $y_i$ you would need something like $\hat y_i = 20 +x_i$ or $\hat y_i = 26 - x_i$, both of which would be worse (shown in pink below).
- If you do not allow an intercept, then the fitted line is $\hat y_i = \frac{342}{55}x_i $ and so the variance of the $\hat y_i$ is over $38$ times the variance of the $y_i$, largely because a line through the origin is nowhere near a sensible model of this data.  To get the variance of the $\hat y_i$  down to that of the $y_i$ you would need something like $\hat y_i = x_i$ or $\hat y_i = - x_i$, neither of which go anywhere near the data.

This is illustrated below:

- the black Os show the points
- the blue regression line minimises the sum of squares of the residuals
- the cyan lines (through the means of the data) illustrate what would make the variance of the fitted values match the variance of the original values
- the red line minimises the sum of squares of the residuals given that the intercept is $0$
- the pink lines illustrate what would make the variance of the fitted data match the variance of the original data given that the intercept is $0$

The blue line is not a particularly good fit to the data, but the others are clearly worse.

[image: regression lines]

Comment: In such a case, where your observations form a _"dot cloud"_ with poor correlation (which disallows linear regression with intercept), and you are sure the actual relationship requires a line through the origin -- in such a case, what would be the better balance line, the one through the **dot cloud's barycentre** or the one **best fit** by least squares method using the vertical distance to the resulting line? When I look at your diagram I consider to undelete my $\displaystyle\beta=\frac{\bar{y}}{\bar{x}}$ suggestion.

Comment: @m-stgt in my example, the red line $\hat y_i = \frac{342}{55}x_i$ gives a sum of squares of the residuals of about $528.4$ while your steeper line  $\hat y_i = \frac{23}{3}x_i$ would have a sum of squares of the residuals of about $643.8$

Comment: Sure, **but --** if you observe rather a "dot cloud" than more linearly arranged points, you should consider also some error in $x_i$ not only in $y_i$. When you take the residuals-sqared-sum in vertical direction only, you expect every $x_i$ as _free of error_, what is (regarding the "dot cloud") highly likely not the case. Thus your model is wrong, you better use the perpendicular distance to the resulting line if $x_i$ and $y_i$ have similar errors. _Or_ you use the line through $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ as simple perfecting.